# Loading jQuery function only when window width > 940px whether by page load or resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-resize

I want a function to load only when the browser window width is greater than 940px.

I can do this on initial page load with:

```
if ( $(window).width() > 940) {
  // my function
}
```

However, doing it the above way won't work on browser resize. I've been able to somewhat get it working on browser resize with the following:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 940) {
     return;
  }
 else {
    // my function
 }
});
```

The problem with this, however, is once the function is loaded, it stays loaded whether the browser window is resized smaller or not. I need to clear the function out or un-load it whenever the window is smaller.

Is there a way to only load a function if the window is larger than 940px and completely remove it if the window is smaller than 940?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where is the _function_?

Comment: Inside the commented area, so it looks like:

if ( $(window).width() > 940) {
  nav_container.waypoint();
}

Answer (score 0):

Do what you need in the first branch where you have `return`.

http://jsfiddle.net/KQSNE/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Managing JavaScript on Responsive Websites](http://viget.com/inspire/managing-javascript-on-responsive-websites).